# Android WebView not showing javascript Google Maps

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, webview

I have this `WebView` with some javascript `Google Maps` in it however they aren't loading while the rest of the `webpage` loads no problem. I tried creating another one and point it to `Google Maps` with the same results.

```
WebView test = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);

test.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
test.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
test.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
test.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);
test.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
test.loadUrl("maps.google.com");
```

They both just load to white. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Any solution for this ?